# Refresh Data on ListGrid SMARTGWT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, smartgwt

I can avoid the refresh in the listGrid SMARTGWT when I do the filter editor because the call to the server is always carried out and I want the filter to apply only to the data in progress.
Thank you.

```
 ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
                grid.setFilterLocalData(true);
                DataSource resultDS = XMLDataSample.parcDataSourceResult();
                resultDS.fetchData(searchForm.getValuesAsCriteria(), new DSCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(DSResponse response, Object rawData, DSRequest request) {

                        RecordList recordList = new RecordList(response.getData()[0].getAttributeAsRecordArray("Result"));
                        grid.setData(recordList);
                    }

                }, dsRequestProperties);
```

Comment: When I type a filter into the listgrid filter, a web service call is made while my need is to do that locally.

Comment: So basically you want to override the functionality of Listgrid filter search. Correct?